# Problem when trying to open txt file with "[" and "]"

Tags: string, perl

I have a problem when I try to open a .txt file with Perl.

The text is basically:

```
function(1,1,[5,-5])
```

And I want to print this line. However, it doesn't print anything.

The code I use is the following:

```
sub open_txt {
# Open a txt file and return then content in an array
my $filename = $_[0];
my @lines;
my $index_row = 0;

open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
# open(my $fh, '<:encoding(iso-8859-7)', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
    while (my $row = <$fh>) {
        chomp $row;
        $lines[$index_row] = $row; 
        $index_row = $index_row + 1;
    }

return @lines;
}

my $filename = 'test.txt';
my @lines = open_txt($filename);
while (my $row = <@lines>) {
    $index_row = $index_row + 1;
    print "[debug] $row\n";
}
```

I get the line printed for these cases:

`function(1,1,[5,-5)` or `function(1,1,5,-5])` or `function(1,1,[])` but not for `function(1,1,[5,-5])` or `function(1,1,[,])` or `function(1,1,[ ])`.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you aware of functions like `push` and `unshift` for adding elements to the ends of  arrrays? Be a lot simpler... Also, obligatory you're missing an minimal **complete** example... *I get the line printed ...* Where's that code?

Comment: Your code doesn't print any lines. Please share the actual code.

Comment: The actual code is in the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (my $row = <@lines>) {
```

means

```
while (my $row = glob(qq<@lines>)) {
```

You should be using

```
for my $row (@lines) {
```